# Android View polymorphism

Tags: android, polymorphism

I have a custom android View that extends **RelativeLayout**:

```
public class ModuleTriggerView extends RelativeLayout
```

On my main activity, I have a ListView with a custom adapter. the layout that describes each line in the ListView is given in **list_item_module.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/module_line_clickable_area"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/module_name_string"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/module_type_string"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/show_module_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/button_show_module" />
```

The **ModuleTriggerView** View is polymorphically extended using 3 different other Views.

How do I set each of the **com.Modules.ModuleTriggerView** to have the right type? (the type of the inheriting class, and not the parent)

Thank you!